# libcurl: suppress output on stdout when invoking curl_easy_perform()

Tags: libcurl

I'm using libcurl to do a simple http GET on a given url. All works fine, including user authentication, but I cannot avoid the printing of an "OK" message when invoking `curl_easy_perform()` ("OK" corresponds to the 200 http return code, I presume).
I've tried to use `CURLOPT_STDERR` to redirect stderr output elsewhere, but actually it seems that the printing is done on stdout.
Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, you should show your code so others can properly help you.

That being said, cURL prints results to stdout by default - could it be that "OK" is simply what your page returns? If that is the case, you may use [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) to redirect the response to a variable or file (or discard it).

Example function that writes the response to a variable (taken from the cURL docs linked above):

```c++
struct memory {
  char *response;
  size_t size;
};
     
static size_t cb(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct memory *mem = (struct memory *)userp;
     
  char *ptr = realloc(mem->response, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(ptr == NULL)
    return 0;  /* out of memory! */
     
  mem->response = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->response[mem->size] = 0;
     
  return realsize;
}
     
struct memory chunk = {0};
     
/* send all data to this function  */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);
     
/* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
```

Comment: The invoked URL is actually a cgi from an IP camera, so the "OK" string is the returned content. Setting writing callback by the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION option effectively resolved my problem. Since I'm not interested in handling the returned content, the writing callback simply returns the value of size * nmemb:

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and still looking for a better solution. What i did right now as  a temporary measure is to memset the data pointer received to zero for the size received in the call back function.

`memset(data,0,size * nmemb);`